# How can I do the slide down effect to not bring my web page back to top when I press the button that actions the effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that my page to stay at the current position scrolling when I press the button to activate the .slideDown() or slideUP() function.
Do you have an ideea how to do that ?

My structure looks like that : 
HTML :

```
<nav class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">

  <ul id="navbar-collapse1" class="hover-effect">
    <li><a href="#" data-hover="Home" class="tagline">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-hover="About" class="tagline">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-hover="Portofolio" class="tagline">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-hover="Contact" class="tagline">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</div>
</nav>

<header>
<ul class="col-lg-12 navbar-fixed-top">
    <a href="#"><li class="toggle-button" data-letterfx="custom[0]">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    </li></a>
</ul>
</header>
```

jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle-button").click(function () {
        $("nav").slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information. By the look of it you are using a framework. Also provide a jsfiddle with the code so we can test and evaluate the problem.

Comment: Are you talking about scrolling or sliding? It seems to me that you are trying to use a slide effect to do a page scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the hash value in your anchor href.

Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to you click event handler

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".toggle-button").click(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("nav").slideDown();
    });
});
```

Also, notice the `e` parameter now being passed in

Comment: Yes r0m4n,this was the thing that I missed. Thanks alot!